# How can I stub a class in this particular case

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I want to do some integration test skiping the last part of my endpoints when a class that I code (using sdk library), get data from a third party API. So my test case is the following:

```
describe('GET /getCustomer/:id', ()=>{

describe('get customer with id 1: ',()=>{
    it('should respond success message', (done) => {
        chai.request(app)
            .get('/api/getCustomer/customerIDsample')
            .end( function(err,res){
                expect(res).to.have.status(SUCCESS);
                done();
            });
    });
  });
});
```

my Express NodeJS API works as:
route -> controller (req,res) -> service (my logic) -> gateway/client.
So the module that I need to stub is gateway/client. Let me show you the endpoint path from start to Client class:

route.js:

```
router.get('/getCustomer/:id', CustomerController.getCustomer
```

);

controller.js:

```
'use strict';

const { UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, SUCCESS, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR } = require('../../constants/httpCodes');

const CustomerService = require('../../services/customerService');

class CustomerController {

    static async getCustomer (req, res) {

        const customerID = req.params.id;
        const customerService = new CustomerService(customerID);

        try {
            const getCustomer = await customerService.getCustomer()
            return res.status(SUCCESS).send(getCustomer);
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send({
                "details": error
            });
        }
    }
}
```

service.js:

```
'use strict';

const validate = require('jsonschema').validate;

const Client = require('../gateways/Client')
const ClientCustomerSchema = require('../schemas/ClientCustomerSchema');

class CustomerService {

    constructor(customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    async getCustomer() {
        const client = new Client(this.customer);
        try {
            const newCustomer = await client.getCustomer();
            return newCustomer;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

client.js: this is my class to wrap an SDK from a API similar than paypal, Client is a fantasy name:

```
'use strict';

const Client = require('Client');
const { client } = require('../config/index');

class openPayClient {

    constructor(customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.client = new Client(
            client.ID,
            client.PRIVATE_KEY
        );
    }

    async getCustomer() {

        return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.client.customers.get(this.customer, function(error, body) {
                if(error) {
                    reject(error)
                } else {
                    resolve(body)
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Of course I did researching but I found anything regarding stub classes in this kind of scenarios when actually you are not using the function/class explicitly in the test file. The module that I need to stub is Client.js, because this one use client.customer.get method that calls an external API through sdk library.

Comment: What does `client` class come from? Show minimal, complete, correct code

Comment: @slideshowp2 I hope new details works !

Comment: nowbady here ? :D